# Using pretty formatting to offset body of log from left

Tags: git-bash

I've been referencing the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats) and playing around with the [log `--pretty=format`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_formatting) for the last hour or so, trying to offset the body of the log message form the left-hand side of the terminal window on Windows but without much luck.

The closest I've managed to get is by using the command: `$ git log --author=Derp -5 --color=always --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h - %s%n%w(80,10)%b'`

Which provides the output format below, what I'm aiming for is the output that's shown below that.

[image]

I did think I'd be able to dispense with `%w(80,10)` in favour of a mix of `%<|(<N>)` and `%>(<N>)', '%>|(<N>)`, but I think I'm misunderstanding the documentation on that section.

Using:

`$ git log --author=Derp -5 --color=always --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h - %s%n%>>(10)""%>%b'`

Gets a similar output to `%w`, but with dirt preceding the body block, however removing the characters that insert the dirt stops the left off-setting from being added.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally worked it out, the left (`%>(<N>)', '%>|(<N>)`) and right (`%<(<N>)', '%<|(<N>)`) offsetting was a red-herring, I hadn't properly investigated the `%w` option, which allows you to specify the line-length, start-offet and newline-offsets using:

`$ git log --author=Derp -5 --color=always --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h - %s%n%w(100,10,10)%b'`

gives the desired output.